# Using Barcode Scanner library

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I cannot handle procedure of finding, pairing and using Zebra Barcode Scanner SDK.

Here is the [SDK](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-android.html). What I have got from the demo source code:

1. I need to have a class (in my case `Application`) which implements `IDcsSdkApiDelegate`.

   ```
   public class LmsApplication extends Application implements IDcsSdkApiDelegate
   ```
2. I need to create instance of `SdkHandler`. Here it is (in the `LmsApplication`)

   ```
   public static SDKHandler sdkHandler;
   sdkHandler = new SDKHandler(this);
   ```
3. Need to do some initialization of `SdkHandler`. All done in `LmsApplication`

   ```
   sdkHandler.dcssdkSetDelegate(this);
   sdkHandler.dcssdkGetAvailableScannersList(mScannerInfoList);
   sdkHandler.dcssdkGetActiveScannersList(mScannerInfoList);
   ```

The JavaDoc actually says that these two methods return a list of Bluetooth devices, but somehow in demo app one of these functions returns a device (scanner) connected to Android Tablet.
But in my program they return nothing, but this shows in Android Monitor:

```
dcssdkGetActiveScannersList() called                                                                
[ 06-05 20:08:42.597  2030: 2047 I/         ]
[JSR82][JBT] JBT jbt_session_service_registration
[ 06-05 20:08:42.597  2030: 2047 I/         ]
[session] session_mutex_lock() +++, mutex: 0xef8301a0
[ 06-05 20:08:42.597  2030: 2047 I/         ]
[session] session_mutex_lock() ---
```

I feel like I'm missing something. Can you point me what?

Comment: *"I need to create instance of SdkHandler. Here it is (in the LmsApplication)"* No, that's a *declaration*. You haven't *created* anything.

Comment: Correct, didn't copy from `Application::onCreate` to question

Comment: The source code for the demo app for the SDK you linked to is available as part of the download.  If you say the demo app works for you, could you look through the demo app's source code to see the differences?

Comment: I did look, but it's kind of confusing, and moreover I have troubles with debugging, as I have to have scanner connected to tablet and I connected to the phone with adb over ip and the connection breaks sometimes during debugging